# UITableview cell height based on imageContent like facebook feed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, feed

I am working on feed concept, where tableview cell height need to auto adjust after image downloading , current i am facing below issue[image]

when you observe above image there are two labels just above the image , after downloading image labels are override by the imageview.

Actual feed should look like below

[image]

here i don't have height constraint for the imageview , because based on image content height will increase , for this i have applied aspect ratio for the imageview.

But after scrolling its working as expected.

please do help on this issue

Comment: Show your code for tableview and tablviewcell. (Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46909418/5638630)

Comment: everything done which is mentioned in a link , if i have only labels then its working fine for me , problem is with the image , which is coming from server , so how can we update tableview cell height after downloading image

Comment: Have you implemented `heightForRowAt`?

Comment: No , i am using Constraints , so i no need to use heightForRowAt method right?

Answer (score 0):

Give Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom Constraints for ImageView. Top constraint to "7 days ago" label. It may work for you.

Write below lines of code in viewDidLoad()

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = Your cell default height

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: what are you doing for image downloading?

Comment: Use "AlamofireImage" for image.

Comment: here problem is not with the image downloading , after downloading image based on the content image view height increasing , but the tableview cell height not updating

Comment: did you give any constant constraints for any UI components?

Comment: not actually , i have not given height constraints at all